# Unable to read data (send by server) at Client Side

Tags: android, sockets, serversocket

I am trying to develop an app in which

1.client sends request to server for connection(IP address+PORT no.)+sends data using "PrintStream"+*Tries to read the data from Server(Using Inputstream)*

2.Client creates the socket.

3.Server reads the data send by Client

4.SERVER writes the data using "PrintStream" at same time point no 3.

Problem is at point 4 Data written by SERVER is not Read by "INPUTSTREAM" of client(Point 1)
I dont know these Simultaneous operation are possible or not.If possible then how.If not then what is the alternate way?

Server Code

```
package com.example.loneranger.ser;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    TextView ip;
    TextView msg;
    String data = "";

    ServerSocket httpServerSocket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);

        ip.setText(getIpAddress() + ":"
                + 8080 + "\n");

        Server server = new Server();
        server.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (httpServerSocket != null) {
            try {
                httpServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getIpAddress() {
        String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                        .nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                        .getInetAddresses();
                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        ip += "IP: "
                                + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }

        return ip;
    }

    private class Server extends Thread {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                httpServerSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);

                while(true){
                    socket = httpServerSocket.accept();

                    HttpResponseThread httpResponseThread =
                            new HttpResponseThread(
                                    socket);
                    httpResponseThread.start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }

    private class HttpResponseThread extends Thread {

        Socket socket;

        HttpResponseThread(Socket socket){
            this.socket = socket;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader BReader;
            PrintWriter printer;
            String request;


            try { InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                BReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                request = BReader.readLine();
Thread.sleep(500);
                printer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);


                printer.print("hello laundu");
                printer.flush();
                String ip123=socket.getInetAddress().toString();
                printer.close();

                BReader.close();

                socket.close();


                data += "Request of " + request
                        + " from "+ ip123 + "\n";
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        msg.setText(data);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Client Code

```
mport android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String response = "";
    TextView textResponse;
    MainActivity activity;
    OutputStream outputStream;
    BufferedReader BReader;
    String request;

    Client(String addr, int port, TextView textResponse) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
        this.textResponse=textResponse;
        this.activity=activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            Server server = new Server(socket);
            server.start();

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(

                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),

                    true);

            out.print("futfujb");
            out.flush();




            /*
             * notice: inputStream.read() will block if no data return
             */


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } /*finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }*/
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        textResponse.setText(response);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
    private class Server extends Thread {
        Socket socket;
        Server(Socket socket)
        {
            this.socket=socket;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {

                try { //Thread.sleep(500);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                            1024);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                    int bytesRead;
                    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                    if(inputStream.available()>0)
                    {
                        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                        }
                    }

                    inputStream.close();
                    socket.close();
            }
             catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Why does the server create a new socket connection? Where is the code that exhibits this problem?

Comment: There is nothing here that corresponds to '(2) server gets request (3) server creates new connection'. There is a new mystery: why do you have a class called `Server` in the client? The solution to your problem is to remove the `available()` test.

Comment: after removing availaible() inputstream is getting stuck.

Comment: The server is reading a line that the client is never sending. The client needs to send a request. It will then come out off the read loop when the server closes the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented above, there is nothing in this code that corresponds to either of these steps:

> 2.Server gets the request creates new SOCKET connection.

(a) There is no request, and (b) the server does not create a new connection. The client creates it. The server accepts it.

> 3.Server reads the data send by Client.

The client doesn't send any data.

There are two problems here (at least):

1. The server is blocking in `readLine()` waiting for a message that the client never sends. So it never gets to its own send, so nothing is received by the client. Have the client send a request, as per the comments.
2. The client is incorrectly using `available()`. Remove this test and let the client fall through into the read loop. It will exit that when the peer (the server) closes the connection.

Comment: But Server is reacting Fine with CHROME browser.Server gets the data written by Crome and Crome displays the data send by server

Comment: A browser sends an HTTP request. Your client doesn't.